# Cs50 PSET 1 Mario less comfortable

Tags: c, cs50

hey thanks for the help:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNH5i.png)

New to programming and trying to understand the logic why the code in line 17 produces the desire result of a left-aligned pyramid. Just trying to fully understand why x= height - y - 1 gives the desired outcome.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image or a link to an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Paste it directly into the question as formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet

```c
for (int x = height - y - 1; x < height; x++)
{
    print("#");
}
```

does not have anything to do with alignment. The pyramid will always be left aligned without a space(`" "`) printing loop, which you don't have in your code and you probably don't need either.

Now let's walk through the iteration to understand what's going on

Consider the `height` to be 5

In the first iteration of the outer loop (i.e `for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)`)

- `y` = 0
- `x` = height - y - 1 = 5 - 0 - 1 = 4

So `x` starts at 4 and stops *before* reaching `height`, i.e 5. So this loop will be executed exactly **1 time**. Which means it'll print a **singular** `#`.

In the second iteration of the outer loop

- `y` = 1
- `x` = height - y - 1 = 5 - 1 - 1 = 3

So `x` starts at 3 and stops *before* reaching `height`, i.e 5. So this loop will be executed exactly **2 times**. Which means it'll print `#` **twice**.

In the third iteration of the outer loop

- `y` = 2
- `x` = height - y - 1 = 5 - 2 - 1 = 2

So `x` starts at 2 and stops *before* reaching `height`, i.e 5. So this loop will be executed exactly **3 times**. Which means it'll print `#` **thrice**.

In the fourth iteration of the outer loop

- `y` = 3
- `x` = height - y - 1 = 5 - 3 - 1 = 1

So `x` starts at 1 and stops *before* reaching `height`, i.e 5. So this loop will be executed exactly **4 times**. Which means it'll print `#` 4 times.

In the fifth and final iteration of the outer loop

- `y` = 4
- `x` = height - y - 1 = 5 - 4 - 1 = 0

So `x` starts at 0 and stops *before* reaching `height`, i.e 5. So this loop will be executed exactly **5 times**. Which means it'll print `#` **5 times**.

So to achieve that logic, is the reasoning behind using `x = height - y - 1`. However there are other ways to do this too-

```c
for (int x = 0; x < y + 1; x++)
{
    print("#");
}
```

This will also work in the same logic, but hopefully with less confusion.

Notice, how **the number of characters printed in each line** matches with **the line number**. So the first line has 1 hash, 2nd has 2 and so on. We can deduce the line number from `y`. For the first line `y = 0`, for the second line `y = 1` and so on. So we can simply add `1` to `y` and set that as our upper bound to print the hashes.

Comment: thank you so much I'd been racking my brain trying to see the logic after stumbling my way through.

Comment: came back to say thank you again, was able to finish the Mario more comfortable in 30 mins because you took the time to explain the logic in such detail.